# pandas group by six months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, pandas-groupby

how are you?

I have a two column dataset:

```
damesano    premio_dir
200810      0.00
200811      52639.97
200904      108775.58
200802      0.00
200707      0.00
```

I want to group by the 'damesano' column so that it is grouped by years and then by semesters and summing the value of the premio_dir column.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Please define "semesters"  What is consider a semester?

Comment: I defined semesters to January-June and July-December :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've defined semesters to January-June and July-December, one thing you could do is

```
 df.groupby([df.damesano // 100, df.damesano % 100 > 6]).premio_dir.sum()
```

With your example data, this gives the following, where `False` corresponds to spring, and `True` to fall:

```
In [52]: df.groupby([df.damesano // 100, df.damesano % 100 > 6]).premio_dir.sum()
Out[52]:
damesano  damesano
2007      True             0.00
2008      False            0.00
          True         52639.97
2009      False       108775.58
Name: premio_dir, dtype: float64
```

Or, with a bit of renaming to make the result look nicer:

```
In [107]: df.groupby([df.damesano // 100, df.damesano % 100 > 6]).premio_dir.sum().rename_axis(['Year', 'Semester']).rename(('Spring', 'Fall').__getitem__, level=1)
Out[107]:
Year  Semester
2007  Fall             0.00
2008  Spring           0.00
      Fall         52639.97
2009  Spring      108775.58
Name: premio_dir, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think I formulated my question the wrong way. In this case, I want to group by year and semester and not just by semester. Im sorry :(